Adding number into an existing contact programmatically does not work in some devices
I need to add numbers into an existing contact in the system contact book. I use the following code to add that is described in many sources:
        val operation = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, contactId)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, number)
            .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
            .build()
        context.contentResolver.applyBatch(AUTHORITY, listOf(operation))

It works perfectly in Pixel 2 emulator, however when I try this on a real Samsung galaxy s21 device it does nothing. The applyBatch returns proper operation result indicating that the new row in the data table has been successfully created, however I don't see it in the contact and when I dump database I don't see the record either.
Moreover when I later tried to create a brand new contact among other I found phone numbers that I had tried to add to other contact before. As if the system cached the insert phone number request and applied it into next contact creation.
Any idea how could this happen and is there a way to fix that without cleaning all the contacts database?
